# randomly rotate objects in adobe illustrator

Tags: object, random, rotation, adobe-illustrator

How to randomly rotate objects in Adobe illustrator. I wanted to ask you that how I could rotate many selected objects which are at the same angle and rotate them at random angle.

Script for adobe illustrator in javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selected objects it's just an array in Document.selection, so:

```js
var min = Number(prompt("Minimum angle?","0"));
var max = Number(prompt("Maximum angle?","360"));

for(var i in activeDocument.selection){
    var angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    activeDocument.selection[i].rotate(angle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works very well but can you please tell me how to do it with max and min value by doing prompt

Comment: Sure, i've added prompt.